# Am trying to run Python in my command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run Python in my command prompt, but when I tried it tells me `python` is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Did you install Python?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you didn't installed python yet, install it! https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html

to run a program from inside the terminal (both in Windows and Linux) it need to be in the environment `PATH` variable - this way the terminal knows where the actual exe/elf is.

For example, if you installed the python in `C:\Python37\python.exe`, the PATH should contain that path.

Please read this article which explains how to add Python to the Windows PATH - https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/